# Python requests module gets the same results despite incrementing page number

Tags: python, ajax, python-requests

The only thing that changes in the URL is the page number, which is incremented after each request.

Other than Selenium or related tools, I’m not sure what approach could be used to traverse the pages. My instinct is that there may be some header/query combination to get the data directly, but I don't know where to find it.

```
url = 'http://therunningbug.co.uk/events/find-races.aspx?EventName=&AddressRegion=&AddressCounty=&Date=&Surface=#Sort=Date&page='

page = 1

while True:

    pageData = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url + str(page)).content)

    articles = pageData.find('div', {'class':"items-content"})

    for a in articles.find_all('article'):
        name = a.find('span', {'itemprop':"name"}).text
        d, t = a.find('time').get('datetime').split('T')

        timeData = t[:-3]

        dateData = d.split('-')
        date = (dateData[1] + '/' + dateData[2] + '/' + dateData[0][2:]).strip()
        description = a.find('p', {'itemprop':"description"}).text.strip()
        webLink = 'http://therunningbug.co.uk' + a.find('a', {'itemprop':"url"}).get('href')
        category = a.find('span', {'class':"surface"}).text
        location = a.find('span', {'class':"region"}).text + ', ' + a.find('span', {'class':"county"}).text

        print name, ' -- name'
        print date, ', ', timeData, ' -- date, time'
        print description, ' -- description'
        print webLink, ' -- website link'
        print category, ' -- category'
        print location, ' -- location\n'

    page += 1
```

Comment: Are you certain that the webserver actually uses the `page` query parameter? If the content doesn't change with only that value changing, then you must assume that it does not.

Comment: Do you know to how one might go about finding the query it uses for the listings on each page?

Comment: Also, it appears to at least use the page parameter indirectly, as one can enter the URL in a browser to get that page's results

Comment: So perhaps the *page itself* uses JavaScript to load other pages? You'll have to analyse what a browser sends and receives here.

Comment: Do you have an instinct that that might be more of a rabbit hole than using a heavier solution like Selenium, or is there a way to easily narrow a single query down (like with Postman [1])? [1] -- in Postman, there are many things being sent/received

Comment: I don't know. That depends on the page. Sorry, I'm not going to analyse the browser-server interaction for you.

Comment: To be clear, I didn't ask for such an analysis (that would be presumptuous), but whether, in general, Selenium might be a rule-of-thumb option in lieu of sifting through queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was probably URL encoding. You can urlencode:

```
url = 'http://therunningbug.co.uk/events/find-races.aspx'
payload = {'page': page}
pageData = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params = payload).content)
```

This also works as there are no complex characters in the URI to really URL encode.

```
url = 'http://therunningbug.co.uk/events/find-races.aspx'
pageData = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url + '?page=' + str(page)).content)
```

See requests documentation for the url encoding. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Complete Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = 1
while True:

    url = 'http://therunningbug.co.uk/events/find-races.aspx'
    payload = {'page': page}
    pageData = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params = payload).content)

    articles = pageData.find('div', {'class':"items-content"})

    for a in articles.find_all('article'):
        name = a.find('span', {'itemprop':"name"}).text
        d, t = a.find('time').get('datetime').split('T')

        timeData = t[:-3]

        dateData = d.split('-')
        date = (dateData[1] + '/' + dateData[2] + '/' + dateData[0][2:]).strip()
        description = a.find('p', {'itemprop':"description"}).text.strip()
        webLink = 'http://therunningbug.co.uk' + a.find('a', {'itemprop':"url"}).get('href')
        category = a.find('span', {'class':"surface"}).text
        location = a.find('span', {'class':"region"}).text + ', ' + a.find('span', {'class':"county"}).text

        print name, ' -- name'
        print date, ', ', timeData, ' -- date, time'
        print description, ' -- description'
        print webLink, ' -- website link'
        print category, ' -- category'
        print location, ' -- location\n'

    page += 1
```